# circular doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

This codes purpose at the moment is to make a circular doubly linked list that displays prisoner numbers that I will later apply the Josephus problem to in a deletion function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* first, *last; // global variables first and last

struct Node* GetNewNode(int x)
{
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = x;
    newNode->next = newNode->prev = newNode;
    first = newNode;
    return newNode;
};
```

I believe something is incorrect in my print or insertion function

```
void insertEnd(int x)
{
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    struct Node* temp = GetNewNode(x);

    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = newNode;
        return;
    }


    last = first->prev;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = first;
    first->prev = temp;
    temp->prev = last;
    last->next = temp;

}
```

This function is not printing the five nodes I am expecting it to print in the for loop in main

```
void printList()
{
    struct Node* temp = first;

    while(temp->next != first)
    {
```

The line below never prints.

```
        printf("prisoner %d| ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d", temp->data);
}



int main()
{
    int n,k;

    printf("How many prisoners are there: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
```

this for loop is trying to assign prisoner numbers to each node added on the list

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        insertEnd(i);
    }

    printList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should get pen and paper and think about the assignments in the `insertEnd` - why is it that you do `last = first` and then reset all the pointers on the `first` for each insertion?

Comment: shouldn't `last` be `first->prev`?

Comment: yes last is first->prev.

Comment: Your `getNewNode` always sets the `first` to point to the newly-created node.

Comment: I see, I switched first for last in the getnewnode and now I believe it is displaying it properly for me.

Comment: Bummer that this was closed. Good question +1. Here's some code: https://repl.it/repls/NiceNovelFunction